# How to subtract the two date time objects using python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to subtract the two date time object using python those are in utc format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").How can i subtract the two object, the output  should be in ITC format(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").Can anyone please help me.

Given below is my sample example:

```
login in-time: 2019-04-23 04:22:50.421406
logout time:2019-04-23 04:34:18.002699
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: now_utc = datetime.now()
>>> now_utc
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 11, 15, 42, 554213)
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> from tzlocal import get_localzone
>>> now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
>>> now_utc
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 5, 46, 18, 313518, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: Can you add this in your question and do proper formatting

Comment: actually log intime i am getting from back end so i don't know how to convert the str obj to date time obj i strucked here

Comment: refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: If they're both `datetime` objects you can just do `a - b`, where `a` and `b` are the two different datetimes.

Comment: thq so much sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dateutil.parser`:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

in_time = 'login in-time: 2019-04-23 04:22:50.421406'
out_time = 'logout time:2019-04-23 04:34:18.002699'

str((dparser.parse(out_time, fuzzy=True) - dparser.parse(in_time, fuzzy=True)))
```

Output:

```
'0:11:27.581293'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Subtract the two date time objects:**

```
from datetime import datetime


t1 = datetime(2019,4,23,8,22,50,421406)
t2 = datetime(2019,4,23,4,55,18,155555)
t3 = t1 -t2
print(t3)
```